# On clicking checkbox hyperlink is getting opened

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

There is a checkbox in our website which has a hyperlink in it, when I use the id to click the checkbox it works on Chrome and Mozilla but not on Edge and IE so for that I user checkbox label and that label contains hyperlink so when I click on using label it opens a new page.

Please suggest how I can handle this?

```
<input class="form-check-input" id="terms" type="checkbox" name="terms" xpath="1">

<label for="terms" xpath="1">I agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="">terms &amp; conditions</a> and <a href="/privacy-policy" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="">privacy policy</a></label>
```

My current code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(paymentpage.getProperty("termsandconditions_id"))));
actions.click();
actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: what exaclty your question is we are not getting?

Comment: Update the question with the definition of `paymentpage`, `getProperty()` and `termsandconditions_id`